# Retrieve data from url while being logged in

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib

I need to retrieve data from a url which requires user to logged in using another url (https). The issue is that the user can only retrieve data while he is logged in (which is established by the cookie set on his machine as long as he keeps logged in).. I am trying to build on these scenarios, but not able to retrieve data while being logged in..these are the steps i am following:

```
 import urllib2
 import urllib

 url1 = 'https://url/user/login/'
 url2 = 'https://url/data/globe/'
 login_data=urllib.urlencode({'username':'username','password':'password','submit':'Log In'})
 req1 = urllib2.Request(url1)
 response = urllib2.urlopen(req1)
 cookie = response.headers.get('Set-Cookie')

 req2 = urllib2.Request(url2)
 req2.add_header('cookie', cookie)
 response = urllib2.urlopen(req2)
 data = response.read()
```

Printing the data response is giving indicators which basically reflect that the session cookie is not set..so private data is not returning..any clues on how to login using a first url and then set the cookie and then retrieve the data while being logged in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I must be stupid.. I wasn't even using the login data i built..so here is what was supposed to happen:

```
 response = urllib2.urlopen(req1, login_data)
```

And everything goes good. Thank you everyone. :-)